# RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time. Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward()

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train SRGAN from scratch. I have read solutions for this type of problem, but it would be great if someone could help me debug my code. The exact error is: "RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad()" Here is the snippet I am trying to train:

```
gen_model = Generator().to(device, non_blocking=True)
disc_model  = Discriminator().to(device, non_blocking=True)
opt_gen = optim.Adam(gen_model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
opt_disc = optim.Adam(disc_model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
from torch.nn.modules.loss import BCELoss

def train_model(gen, disc):
  for epoch in range(20):
    run_loss_disc = 0
    run_loss_gen = 0
    for data in train:
      low_res, high_res = data[0].to(device, non_blocking=True, dtype=torch.float).permute(0, 3, 1, 2),data[1].to(device, non_blocking=True, dtype=torch.float).permute(0, 3, 1, 2)
      #--------Discriminator-----------------
     
      gen_image = gen(low_res)
      gen_image = gen_image.detach()
      disc_gen = disc(gen_image)
      disc_real = disc(high_res)
      p=nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
      loss_gen = p(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))
      
      loss_real = p(disc_gen, torch.zeros_like(disc_gen))
      loss_disc = loss_gen + loss_real
      opt_disc.zero_grad()
      loss_disc.backward()
      
      run_loss_disc+=loss_disc
      #---------Generator--------------------
      cont_loss = vgg_loss(high_res, gen_image)
      adv_loss = 1e-3*p(disc_gen, torch.ones_like(disc_gen))
      gen_loss = cont_loss+(10^-3)*adv_loss
      opt_gen.zero_grad()
      gen_loss.backward()
      opt_disc.step()
      opt_gen.step()
      run_loss_gen+=gen_loss
    print("Run Loss Discriminator: %d", run_loss_disc)
    print("Run Loss Generator: %d", run_loss_gen)

train_model(gen_model, disc_model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your `disc_gen` value was discarded by the first `backward()` call, as it says.

It should work if you change the discriminator part a bit:

```
gen_image = gen(low_res)
disc_gen = disc(gen_image.detach())
```

and add this at the start of the generator part:

```
disc_gen = disc(gen_image)
```